# Why pixel is not changing color

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making pseudo paint on C++ (near zero experience in C++ ) using SFML library.
I made a separate function to edit the image and "tool 0" is basically a pencil. When I try to pass this args to my function it doesn't work, but when I do the same without passing this to drawOnImage func it works normally.
I've cut out extra parts on the presented code

I have tried to pass x and y of mouse position as separate args (without the use of Vector), but this doesn't help

```
void drawOnImage(sf::Color color, int tool, sf::Texture canvas, sf::Image image, sf::Vector2i vector);

int main()
{
    sf::Image image;
    image.create(windowWidth, windowHeight, sf::Color::White);
    sf::Texture canvas;
    sf::Color currentColor = sf::Color::Black;  // Color
    int currentTool = 0; // instrument that is currently chosen
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    int mousedown = 0;
    mainWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);
    canvas.loadFromImage(image);
    sprite.setTexture(canvas);
while (mainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        canvas.loadFromImage(image);
        sf::Event event;
        while (mainWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                mainWindow.close();
            else if ((event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved) && (mousedown == 1)) 
            {
                canvas.update(mainWindow);
                drawOnImage(currentColor, currentTool, canvas, image, sf::Mouse::getPosition(mainWindow));
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            {
                mousedown = 1;
                drawOnImage(currentColor, currentTool, canvas, image, sf::Mouse::getPosition(mainWindow));
                //image.setPixel(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mainWindow).x, //IT WORKS but drawOnImage does not 
 sf::Mouse::getPosition(mainWindow).y, sf::Color::Black);
}
void drawOnImage(sf::Color color, int tool, sf::Texture canvas, sf::Image image,sf::Vector2i vector) {
    if (tool == 0) {
        image.setPixel(vector.x,vector.y, sf::Color::Black);
    }
}
```

I am sure that I simply don't know some of c++ features like passing the address of the object rather than name, but I can't figure this out by myself

Comment: You could start by formatting your code properly, so it's readable. Hint: [Clang Format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Comment: So I was correct about referencing problem, yay! Gonna find some information about that aspect. It works, thanks !

Comment: @JesperJuhl yep wish I knew how to

Comment: That's where my "Hint" link comes into the picture ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl yeah, thanks man, I installed clang and now getting used to format before committing :)

Answer (score 0):

After you modify an image, you need to load it onto the texture again, so you need to call this line again:

```
canvas.loadFromImage(image);
```